How to search for a path in a project folder using cmd in windows
I have a big project folder and I need to do a scan for a particular path inside the folder. When I am trying to get the path using command line, it returns some other results too. I tried the following :-
sql-scan dir "\tmp_ejb\src\com\hsbnk\tmup\util\" /s
sql-scan dir "\com\hsbnk\tmup\util*" /s

These are not worked. I want to scan the exact path folder (the files inside util folder) files.
Please advice. Thanks.

You are using a program, not writing if/then/else programming code. Your question would be better suited to [su]. Please delete here and repost there. Also, you're assuming readers know how sql-scan works. Maybe include some background. AND most importantly your goal is not clear, "Search for a path in a project Folder" . Do you mean search for /path/to/something in the text of FILES in one folder, OR do you mean search for a child folder  subpath/below/currentDirectory :  i.e. from /base you want to find /base/subpath/below/currentDirectory ? Good luck.
